# почему этот код возвращает false?

Tags: javascript, массивы

```
let nums = [1,2,3,4]; 
nums.every( (item) => {typeof item === 'number'} )
```

есть массив состоящий из одних цифр. Каждый элемент возвращает true если проверять с помощью typeof,
например: `nums.forEach( item => console.log(typeof item === 'number'))` выведет true 4 раза.
Но почему тогда метод every который должен возвращать true, если каждый вызов возвращает true в этот раз возвращает false

Comment: Потому что ваша функция возвращает undefined

Comment: return отсутствует

Comment: Укажите язык программирования в метках к вопросу.

Answer (score 4):

В функции нет return

```
let nums = [1,2,3,4]; 
nums.every( (item) => typeof item === 'number')
```

или так

```
let nums = [1,2,3,4]; 
nums.every( (item) => {return typeof item === 'number'})
```